# Phone is trying to store incoming SMS messages on SIM card

Tags: sms, sim-card, nexus-5x, roaming

My Nexus 5X has stopped being able to receive SMS messages. Every time I'm supposed to get a text, I instead see a notification: "SIM card storage is full -- No more space for SMS messages on SIM card. You may need to delete some messages."

I have never configured the phone to use SIM card storage (don't even know of such an option). When I click the notification, I see an empty list titled "SIM card messages" in Messenger.

I'm currently traveling abroad and roaming (Sprint subscriber on Chunghwa). Sprint was having an outage with international roaming for several hours; it just came back on and the problem started soon thereafter.

Running latest version of Android N.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Mine is doing the same thing right now

Comment: I never found an answer, but the problem resolved itself a few days later (possibly after I left Taiwan). One possible explanation is that Sprint or Chunghwa was spamming the phone with voicemail notification SMSs, which are not supposed to be displayed to the user. Or they could have been delivering messages using the wrong [SMS class](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=544#1.1.9).

Comment: I too experienced similar problem and I get it solved by deleting a single SMS from the sim card. New SMS where saved to phone after doing that